# TYPO3 Form Framework e-mail-finisher with staticText

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I made a form with the TYPO3-FormFramework (Version 10.4.12). The form contains a lot of staticText-Elements, which don't show up at the summary-page and in the emails. The Template-part looks like this

```
<formvh:renderAllFormValues renderable="{form.formDefinition}" as="formValue">
...
          {formvh:translateElementProperty(element:formValue.element, property: 'label')}
...
             <f:if condition="{formValue.value}">
                <f:then>
                   <f:if condition="{formValue.isMultiValue}">
                      <f:then>
...
                          <f:for each="{formValue.processedValue}" as="value">
                              <tr>
                                 <td>{value}</td>
                               </tr>
                           </f:for>
                                 </table>
                       </f:then>
                       <f:else>
                            <table>
                               <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <f:format.nl2br>formValue.processedValue}</f:format.nl2br>
...
</formvh:renderAllFormValues>
```

(identical with the original-Template.)

The Formdefinition in the yaml-File containts standard definitions like

```
renderables:
  -
    properties:
      text: 'Antrag auf Mitgliedschaft'
      elementClassAttribute: h3
    type: StaticText
    identifier: statictext-10
    label: ''
  -
```

Does anyone know how to output the staticTexts (and/or contentElements used in forms)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In [Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/StaticText.yaml](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/form/blob/v10.4.17/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/StaticText.yaml), the YAML configuration of the `StaticText` field includes a Form variant:

```
variants:
  -
    identifier: hide-1
    renderingOptions:
      enabled: false
    condition: 'stepType == "SummaryPage" || finisherIdentifier in ["EmailToSender", "EmailToReceiver"]'
```

This variant will disable the rendering of the field if the condition is met, in this case:

- on a summary page
- in the two email finishers

You can learn more about Form variants in the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html).

### Possible solution

First of all, we need to alter the variant of the field type `StaticText` in your custom Form configuration:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            StaticText:
              variants:
                -
                  identifier: hide-1
                  renderingOptions:
                    enabled: true
```

This change already allows to render the StaticText's **Header** (label) in summary pages and emails. But the text value is still missing, as only **processed** values (means: user input) are rendered there.

To also render the value stored in the **Text** field, we need to extend the Fluid templates. The following partial will work in *SummaryPage.html*, as well as in the email finisher templates:

```
<f:if condition="{formValue.value}">
    <f:then>
        [default processing here]
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:if condition="{0: formValue.element.type} == {0: 'StaticText'}">
            <f:then>
                {formValue.element.properties.text}
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                -
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

As you can see, we add another condition which checks if the current form element in the `f:for` loop is of type `StaticText`. If this is the case, we render the text property. For all other field types with an empty value, we still render the hyphen.

Comment: if you want to target a specific field only,
one can use         <f:if condition="{0: formValue.element.identifier} == {0: '--insertIentifierValue--'}">